# Сохранить данные из StringGrid в ранее открытый файл

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

```
procedure TForm7.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  t,r: tstringlist;
begin
   StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:=Form1.CheckListBox1.Items.ValueFromIndex[Form1.CheckListBox1.ItemIndex];
   try
     t:=tstringlist.Create;
     r:=tstringlist.Create;
     begin
       t.LoadFromFile('files/Res/Prepod/1.'+inttostr(Form1.CheckListbox1.ItemIndex)+'spisok.txt'); 

       for i:=1 to stringgrid1.RowCount-1 do                      
          stringgrid1.Rows[i].Clear;

       stringgrid1.ColCount:=1;
       stringgrid1.RowCount:=t.Count;

       for i:=1 to t.Count-1 do
       begin
          r.DelimitedText:=t[i];

          if r.Count>stringgrid1.ColCount then         
            stringgrid1.ColCount:=r.Count;

          stringgrid1.Rows[i].Assign(r);
       end;
     end;
  except
  on E:exception do
     showmessage('Файла не существует');
  end;
end;
```

Есть код, который выгружает из файла внутри корневой папки данные и выводит их в  `StringGrid`. Как сделать обратную функцию?

Вот такая входящая информация:
[image: исходящая информация]

А это получается исходящая, если я выгружаю уже из таблицы.
[image: исходящая]

Как сделать, чтобы сохранялось как входная?

Comment: Пройтись по Cells[i][j] и записать.

Comment: Поправьте отступы в коде. Они вводят в заблуждение.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял - то колонка одна, это упрощает задачу.
    *//stringgrid1.ColCount:=1;*
Если бы колонок было больше, то можно было бы добавить по ним цикл и немного поменять формат файла. Конечно можно под любой подогнать, но я так понял, что сейчас просто одни строки. Строка = значение.

```
procedure TForm7.SaveStingGrid2File(FileName : string);    
var
  i: integer;
  StringListt: TStringList;
begin
  StringList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i := 1 to stringgrid1.RowCount-1 do                      
      StringList.Add(stringgrid1.Cells[0, i]);
    StringList.SaveToFile(FileName);   
  finally
    StringList.free; 
  end;
end;
```

Для нескольких колонок можно вывести число колонок первой строкой, а затем сохранить вместе с циклом по колонкам

```
procedure TForm7.SaveStingGrid2File(FileName : string);    
var
  i, j: integer;
  StringList: TStringList;
begin
  StringList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    StringList.Add(IntToStr(stringgrid1.ColCount));
    for i := 1 to stringgrid1.RowCount-1 do                      
      for j := 1 to stringgrid1.ColCount-1 do                      
        StringList.Add(stringgrid1.Cells[j, i]);
    StringList.SaveToFile(FileName);   
  finally
    StringList.free; 
  end;
end;
```

Кстати, лично от меня рекомендация (не сочтите за наглость)
1) Переменные и компоненты лучше называть осмысленно.
Form7, StringGrid1 - когда их десятки и сотни,запутаться легко в своем коде, даже на следующий день. Если одна форма, то не так актуально
2) Try except лучше ставить непосредственно перед критическим кодом с   потенциальной ошибкой, так читабельнее
     try
       loadfromfile
     except
     end
3) Функции лучше делать более универсальные.
не procedure TForm7.SaveStingGrid2File(FileName : string);
а procedure SaveStingGrid2File(StringGrid : TStringGrid; FileName : string);
это поможет избежать дублирования кода.

Comment: Не учите людей писать неправильный код. Пустая конструкция `except end` (без обработки исключения) - это очень вредная конструкция.

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли код. `ColCount := 1` это просто сброс старых ячеек (зачем - оставим это на совести автора). А дальше у него идет  `stringgrid1.ColCount:=r.Count;`