# Как сохранить значения из StringGrid в файл?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Вот кусок кода, в котором вычисляется сумма на пересечениях строк и столбцов, как мне полученные значения сохранять сразу в файл?

```
procedure TForm1.MenuItem5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  z,c,i,j: integer;
begin
  for j:=1 to RowCount-1 do begin
    for i:=1 to ColCount-1 do begin
      z := StrToInt(StringGrid1.cells[i,0]);
      c := StrToInt(StringGrid1.cells[0,j]);
      StringGrid1.cells[i,j] := IntToStr(z + c);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Вот исходный код:

Comment: Для сохранения в текстовом виде - можно использовать TStringList

Comment: Посмотрите [вот этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/533673/223235).